# Changing column datatype from DECIMAL(9,0) to DECIMAL(15,0)

Tags: sql, teradata

Can you please help me concerning this matter (I didn´t found it in the Teradata documentation, which is honestly little overwhelming): My table had this column -BAN DECIMAL(9,0)-, and now I want to change it to - BAN DECIMAL(15,0) COMPRESS 0.- How can I do it? What does COMPRESS constraint 0. or any other mean anyway? 
I hope this is possible, and I don`t have to create a new table and then copy the data form the old table. The table is very very big - when I do COUNT(*) form that table I get this error: 2616 numeric overflow occurred during computation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax diagram for ALTER TABLE doesn't seem to support directly changing a column's data type. ([Teradata SQL DDL Documentation](http://www.info.teradata.com/templates/eSrchResults.cfm?prodline=&txtpid=&txtrelno=&txtttlkywrd=SQLREF,TNTSEQ&rdsort=Title&srtord=Asc&nm=SQL%20Reference)). `COMPRESS 0` compresses zeroes. Teradata supports a lot of different kinds of compression.

Numeric overflow here probably means you've exceeded the range of an integer. To make that part work, just try casting to a bigger data type.  (You don't need to change the column's data type to do this.)

```
select cast(count(*) as bigint) 
from table_name;
```

Comment: So basically, you suggest to create new table and carry the data from the existing table to the newly created table? There´s no other way?

Comment: You can add a new column instead of a new table, copy the data, drop the old column, and rename the new column. (Syntax is in the DDL documentation.) I think I've seen discussions on the Teradata user forums that say creating a new table is often faster, though.

Answer (score 2):

You asked three different questions:

1. You cannot change the data type of a column from `DECIMAL(9,0)` to `DECIMAL(15,0)`.  Your best bet would be to create a new column (NEW_BAN), assign values from your old column, drop the old column and rename  NEW_BAN back to BAN).
2. `COMPRESS 0` is not a constraint.  It means that values of "zero" are compressed from the table, saving disk space.
3. Your `COUNT(*)` is returning that error becasue the table has more than 2,147,483,647 rows (the max value of an INTEGER).  Cast the result as BIGINT (as shown by Catcall).

And I agree, the documentation can be overwhelming.  But be patient and focus only on the SQL titles for your exact release.  They really are well written.

Comment: Hi Bob! Thanks for the reply. i like the suggestion about adding a new column and copying data in that new column. 
what I would like to know is it possible to keep the same order of columns i.e. Can I place the new column on the same spot where the old column is, or this column can only be at the end of the table?

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `ALTER TABLE` to change the data type from `DECIMAL(9,0)` to `DECIMAL(15,0)` because it cross the byte boundary required to store the values in the table. For Teradata 13.10, see the Teradata manual for *SQL Data Definition Language Detailed Topics* pages 61-65 for more details on using `ALTER TABLE` to change column data types.